# I'm no longer able to grok the SRTM30 elevation data, but get this error now. How do I get past this?

Tags: add-on

TypeError: Converting py args to operator properties:  enum "EPSG:4326" not found in ('EPSG:3857', 'EPSG:27700')

Comment: This sounds like a bug to me so this site is not suitable for the question and furthermore I guess this is about a third party add-on so another reason why the question is off-topic here. You should go to the official add-on site and ask for help or report the bug there.

Comment: try this one: https://snipboard.io/ymLkSg.jpg

Comment: Hi, @HarryMcKenzie This Q left open because of your comment (a setting, not a bug..) which may be useful to others, even though Robert has a fix. If you think so, too, perhaps make it into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I reinstalled the BlenderGIS add-on and that solved the problem.